# Calculating factorials with linear systems, an approach for finding generalizations?

Tags: soft-question, numerical-methods, factorial, numerical-linear-algebra, gamma-function

Consider the linear equation system:

$$\bf Mx = b$$

$${\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{cccccccc}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
-2&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&-3&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&-4&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-5&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&-6&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&-7&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&-8&1
\end{array}\right]\hspace{0.5cm} {\bf b} = \left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{array}\right]$$

It is easy to see that these are equations corresponding to the recursive definition of the *factorial* function:
$$n! = 1\cdot 2\cdots n, \forall n \in \{1,\cdots,8\}\\\text{Expressed recursively: }\\n! = n\cdot (n-1)! \Leftrightarrow\\ - n \cdot (n-1)!+n!=0$$

---

**Now to the question**: Can we use this fact to try and find interpolations / generalizations to arguments $\in \mathbb R$ to the factorial function the by some linear algebraic numerical method. If it is possible to do so, which particular one will yield the famous $\Gamma$ function?

$$t\to \Gamma(t), \forall t\in \mathbb R:\\\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty \tau^{t-1}e^{-\tau}d\tau$$Having the following connection to the factorial function :$$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!\hspace{0.5cm} \forall n\in\mathbb N$$