# Linear equation systems for verifying combinatorial identities.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, soft-question, least-squares

In the same idea as of [this question on factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391179/calculating-factorials-with-linear-systems-an-approach-for-finding-generalizati); since we showed we can build linear systems for calculating factorials, maybe in the same way we can build linear equation systems to verify theorems in combinatorics?

---

**Own work so far:**

We can for example define the [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle) recursively on a grid:

$$\text{Boundary condition: }\hspace{0.125cm}g = \left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}1&1&1&1&1\\\hline1&0&0&0&0\\\hline1&0&0&0&0\\\hline1&0&0&0&0\\\hline1&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]\hspace{0.125cm} \text{ and filter: } f = \left[\begin{array}{r|r}-1&1\\\hline1&0\end{array}\right]$$
we can set up the least squares problem: 
$${\bf v_o} =\min_{\bf v}\{\|{\bf Fv}\|_2^2 + {\bf C_g}\|{\bf v-g}\|_2^2\}$$
Where $\bf F$ is the matrix representation of the convolution operator of filter $f$. $\bf g$ is a vectorization of the boundary condition values and $\bf C_g$ is a diagonal matrix encoding which grid points are on the boundary.

The solution will propagate "automatically" giving us the well known binomial coefficients. In the same idea we can get multinomial coefficients, but we need to handle data and filters in more dimensions.

---

Is this enough or do we need to step outside of our comfy linear framework to prove anything of interest?

Comment: You are speaking about solution but there is no equation, so how will the *solution propagate automatically*?

Comment: @Gribouillis you are right, will add it.

Comment: When you write $v-g$, it implies that $v$ is a 5x5 matrix, but in this case $F v$ is not defined, so the least square problem above is currently meaningless. Can you change this?

Comment: no it doesn't, it is not intended to be a matrix, just a depiction of the grid explaining the data and the convolution operator.